# Multipass Rendering Vertex Buffer Organisation

Tags: directx11, hlsl

I am working on a Renderer that should do a Depth Prepass before rendering the desired geometry.
For this I have a Vertex and Pixel Shader that outputs to the Depth Texture.
After that it should render the same geometry using different shaders with texture and such.
My question is how should I organize the Data on CPU side (classes/structs)?
The "Main" Vertex Buffer Layout contains

```
Position
Normal
TexCoord
Color
(BoneWeight)
```

The Depth Pass only needs `Position`
Do I need to store two different Layouts and keep two different Vertex Buffers to reduce Bandwidth?

Comment: Do you need to actually save a depth texture?  Can you not just use the Z-buffer and send the models twice within the same render pass?  (Further, you can probably then just leave out the first step if ever you are using TBDR hardware)